# Getting Error "Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY"

Tags: android

I'm getting an error when trying to use an external jar file to access Forward facing camera in Android. But when we try to load, i get error `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY` on my console window of myeclipse. 
"
when i saw a log file, the error was "unavailable shared library `com.sprint.hardware.twinCamDevice`

Answer (score 0):

you're required to add the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-library android:name="com.sprint.hardware.twinCamDevice" android:required="false"/>
```

note: android:required="false" only works with API 5 level and above so to support 1.5 and 1.6 devices you have to "fragment" and release a separate apk (unless someone can figure out how to load the shared lib from code and avoid using "uses-library" in the manifest for 2.0 and above)